# Best Data Structure for ordered list of connected users

Tags: websockets, dictionary, queue

I have three attributes for a user: `connectionId` (e.g. "sd4-h4sdg-u4j-a2rr3"), `userName`, and `placeInLine`.

I can't think of a single data structure that will handle my scenario of only allowing a single user to work on a given webpage resource and advancing the line of people as each active user leaves their connection. I am using C# / SignalR with jQuery.

When a user (Adam) hits the page, if this proposed data structure is empty, they get to interact with the page. The next user who comes along (Bob) while Adam is working gets put in line. So we store his userName, connectionId, and place in line as `1`. Carl comes along and gets put in line as well, getting `placeInLine=2`. David is `3`, etc.

Now, in a perfect world, everyone would wait patiently for their turn, and get prompted when the user in front of them disconnects so they can have their turn on the page. In this scenario, a `Queue` would work. However: If Carl leaves, we cannot simply remove him from the `Queue` since he is in the middle `[B, C, D]`. I want this code to scale so rebuilding a queue with each change is not an option.

If I were using a `Dictionary`, I could have the `userName` as the key, with a value of the `placeInLine`. But in this scenario, I cannot get the next user, since `Get()` happens via Key. If the `placeInLine` int is the key, I cannot remove a user based on username since `Remove()` is also done by key.

Am I naive for assuming this should be possible with a single data structure?

Comment: What's wrong with the good old linked list?

Comment: Why remove them from the queue when they leave? At worst, the connection attempt will fail if they aren’t there anymore, and you will simply move on to the next item in the queue.

Comment: Why would a sorted list have an id of where they are in the list?

Comment: Use a queue, but if you identify a user that's returning, simply let them stand in the same place in line.

Comment: Going with the crowd here -- this is almost THE canonical use case for a queue data structure. Push arriving users onto the end, if they leave, set their status flag to 'gone'. Pop each user off the front, check their flag, and either let them in or skip it and pop the next one.

Comment: Have you actually encountered a noticeable performance problem doing *whatever you're already doing?* If not, how many users so you realistically expect in the queue at any given time? How many of which operations will you need to preform in what interval?

Comment: Also, why can only one user at a time access this resource? That sounds like a bigger problem that needs addressing.

Comment: @user1118321 Possibly: http://xyproblem.info/ ... Also possibly not. Could just be a business requirement/decision. But, I think the question (and answer) are relevant to other similar queueing questions you'd find in other human-queueing situations. (Like a game queue ... if such things still exist in our "serverless" world...)

Comment: Please read [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing/243450) before attempting to ask more questions that are opinion based that invite argumentative discussion because they do not have a single agreed upon answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you choose might depend on the particular load you anticipate.

But, I'd start with a simple `Queue`. Possibly extended with a naive *O(n)* complexity `Remove(item)`. Or, use a `Dictionary` or `Map` to index "removed" users. As you `pop()` items out of the `Queue`, just ignore "removed" users and re-`pop()`.

You could potentially micro-optimize further, but, I'm already skeptical that the complexity of adding an index is a necessary optimization. I wouldn't likely fuss about unless I had strong evidence that the *n* in my *O(n)* `Remove()` method will be significant.